# Responsive outlook emailer not center

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

Hi I am having problem with outlook not centering my table part.
it consists of two columns which are left aligned.They are centering in gmail and outlook on desktop but not on mobile.I guess that align left in two columns is giving me an issue.Please help me out.

```
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="padding:0 0 0 10px;">
          <tr>
          <td align="center" class="middle">
          <div align="center">
        <center>
        <!--[if mso]>
        <table style="width: 300px;"><tr><td>
        <![endif]-->
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" width="45%" height="158" bgcolor="#006699"><tr>
<td style="padding: 0;" align="left" class="responsive-image middle">
                      <img src="http://www.eruditus.com/emailer/0418_responsive_columbia/bg.jpg" style="display: block; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
</td>
                  </tr></table>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" width="45%" bgcolor="#0093d4" height="158px"><tr>
<td width="" style="padding: 0 0 0 0; background-color: #0093d4; vertical-align: top;" bgcolor="#0093d4" valign="top">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#0093d4">
<tr>
<td style="color: #fff; background-color: #0093d4; vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px; line-height: 20px; padding: 5px 0 0;" bgcolor="#0093d4" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                  <td style="color: #fff; background-color: #0093d4; vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px; line-height: 20px; padding: 0;" bgcolor="#0093d4" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
<tr>
<td width="56" style="color: #fff; background-color: #0093d4; vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px; line-height: 20px; padding: 5px 0 0 10px;" bgcolor="#0093d4" valign="top">Email: </td>
                                    <td width="273" style="color: #fff; background-color: #0093d4; vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px; line-height: 20px; padding: 0;" bgcolor="#0093d4" valign="top"><a href="mailto:epm_columbia@eruditus.com" style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none; font-size: 12px; display: block; padding: 5px 0 0;">EPM_columbia@eruditus.com</a></td>
                                </tr>
<tr>
<td style="color: #fff; background-color: #0093d4; vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px; line-height: 20px; padding: 0 0 0 10px;" bgcolor="#0093d4" valign="top">Phone: </td>
                                    <td style="color: #fff; background-color: #0093d4; vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px; line-height: 0px; padding: 0;" bgcolor="#0093d4" valign="top"><span style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 20px;">+91 22 6162 3112(India)</span></td>
                                </tr>
<tr>
<td style="color: #fff; background-color: #0093d4; vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px; line-height: 0; padding: 0;" bgcolor="#0093d4" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td style="color: #fff; background-color: #0093d4; vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px; line-height: 0; padding: 0;" bgcolor="#0093d4" valign="top"><span style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 20px;">+971 044302011(Dubai)</span></td>
                                </tr>
<tr>
<td style="color: #fff; background-color: #0093d4; vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px; line-height: 0; padding: 0;" bgcolor="#0093d4" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td style="color: #fff; background-color: #0093d4; vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px; line-height: 0; padding: 0;" bgcolor="#0093d4" valign="top"><span style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 20px;">+1 862 252 5823(USA)</span></td>
                                </tr>
<tr>
<td style="color: #fff; background-color: #0093d4; vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px; line-height: 0; padding: 0;" bgcolor="#0093d4" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                  <td style="color: #fff; background-color: #0093d4; vertical-align: top; font-size: 12px; line-height: 0; padding: 0;" bgcolor="#0093d4" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>


</table>
</td>  </tr>
         </table>           

</center>
</div>
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="600" class="content" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; max-width: 600px;">
           <tr><td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666666;" height="10"> </td>
            </tr>
          <tr><td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666666; padding: 0;" align="center" class="responsive-image">

                <a href="http://www.eruditus.com/programmes/columbia/columbia-mc.html" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;" target="_blank">
                <img src="http://www.eruditus.com/emailer/0419_columbia/clickhere.png" align="middle" width="277" height="58" alt="click_program" style="display: block; max-width: none !important; margin: 0 auto;" /></a>
              </td>
            </tr></table></td>
            </tr><tr><td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #666666;" height="10"> </td>
            </tr></table><!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<![endif]--></td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is use a Media Query to check whether the screen size is less than a certain size to display responsive layouts. e.g:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px;) {
    //Responsive CSS styling
}
```

Using this you can center those tables as you would with a normal webpage. e.g:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px;) {
    td[class="responsive-align"] {
        margin: 0 auto !important;
        float: none !important;
        align: center !important; //If this line centers your text, remove it.
    }
}
```

Email clients are very pedantic, and take a long time to understand what you can do with each one, and what their limits are.

From my experience with responsive designs and Outlook especially you need to lay out your tables like this for them to drop down effectively:

```
<table align="left">
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table align="right">
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

With Outlook, it's best to make sure you have `5px` or larger in between the two tables so that it can add it's own spacing in (That you can't do anything about). So, for a table of `600px` width, you'd have each of your tables with a width of `295px` for a good enough amount of spacing.

Hope this helps :)